# How to record phone calls in iphone using programming?

Tags: iphone, phone-call, recording

I need to know can we record phone calls in iphone. if possible then how can we do it using coding.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is an iPhone Call Recorder theoretically possible?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1809347/is-an-iphone-call-recorder-theoretically-possible)

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Not possible. Otherwise there would be about 400 apps in the app store that could do it.