# Can we fire an event when ever there is Incoming and Outgoing call in iphone?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, events, phone-call

Can I fire an event when ever there is Incoming and Outgoing call ends on iphone? Axample of an event is calling a webservice .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can, but not necessarily immediately.

There is a framework, called the CoreTelephony framework, which has a `CTCallCenter` class.  One of the properties on this class is the [`callEventHandler` property](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CTCallCenter/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009604-CH1-DontLinkElementID_2).  This is a block that gets fired when then *state* of a phone call changes.  For example:

```
CTCallCenter *callCenter = ...; // get a CallCenter somehow; most likely as a global object or something similar?

[callCenter setCallEventHandler:^(CTCall *call) {
  if ([[call callState] isEqual:CTCallStateConnected]) {
    //this call has just connected
  } else if ([[call callState] isEqual:CTCallStateDisconnected]) {
    //this call has just ended (dropped/hung up/etc)
  }
}];
```

That's *really* about all you can do with this.  You don't get access to any phone numbers.  The only other useful tidbit of information is an identifier property on `CTCall` so you uniquely identify a `CTCall` object.

**CAUTION**:

This event handler is *not* invoked unless your app is in the foreground!  If you make and receive calls while the app is backgrounded, the event handler will not fire *until your app becomes active again*, at which point (according to the documentation linked to above) the event handler will get invoked once for each *call* that has changed state while the app was in the background.

Comment: If my app originates an outgoing call and subscribes to the disconnect event, in my event handler can I send a local message that will prompt the user to return to my app? Or do you know of a less cumbersome way to return focus to an app after an outgoing call ends?

Answer (score 1):

No but you do get callbacks into the app when those events happen.

```
    -(void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application{
        //our app is going to loose focus since thier is an incoming call
        [self pauseApp];
    }

    -(void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application{
            //the user declined the call and is returning to our app
            [self resumeApp];
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't necessarily means that there is an incoming call. Other app, notification or the home button will fire it.

Answer (score 0):

No. As of the current SDK, this is not possible. Apple does not allow apps to have such hooks.

Comment: Hmm. Didn't know about this. I am correct in thinking you cannot have your app "wake up" in response to a call, though? You have to wait until it enters the foreground (by user input) again?

Comment: that's correct.  It's simply a way to know that stuff happened and react to it, but only when your app is active.