# Is it possible to record incoming or outgoing call in iPhone?

Tags: ios, iphone

I am trying to record incoming and outgoing calls in iPhone... Is it possible to record calls in iOS ?

Please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Asked before many times

Answer (score 0):

**Yes you can.**

With the use of `AudioToolbox` and `libkern/OSAtomic.h`

First of all you need to trigger when an incoming call coming.

[Fire an event when ever there is Incoming and Outgoing call in iphone?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6798426/5215474)

Recording the call this is what you exactly looking for.
  [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21571219/5215474)

**Note:**

Apple allows these hooks only when your application in foreground.
Conditions that allow your app runs in background:
For tasks that require more execution time to implement, you must request specific permissions to run them in the background without their being suspended.

> In iOS, only specific app types are allowed to run in the background:
>
> ```
> Apps that record audio content while in the background
>
> Apps that keep users informed of their location at all times, such as a navigation app
>
> Apps that support Voice over Internet Protocol (VoIP)
>
> Apps that need to download and process new content regularly
>
> Apps that receive regular updates from external accessories
> ```

[Reference link](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW23)

Comment: "Fire an event when ever there is Incoming and Outgoing call in iphone?"  -> If my app is killed then ?

Comment: Apple constrained to have some limitations while devolopment of apps. This also falls under this concern.

Comment: Yes i know. thats'y i asked Is it possible or not ? because i want to record every incoming and outgoing call while app is active or not..

Answer (score -1):

You can go through this link below:

[Record the conversation of phone - ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13656753/record-the-conversation-of-phone-ios)

There is no public API for recording the calls made (or received) by the built-in Phone app.

You will have to implement your own phone calling mechanism. You'll probably want to use VoIP. (That is what Google Voice uses, for example.) You'll need to run your own server on the Internet, or contract with an existing VoIP service. You'll want to use in-app purchase to let the user buy minutes, because it costs money to run your own server or use a third-party service.