# Record the conversation of phone - ios

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, record, phone-call

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is an iPhone Call Recorder theoretically possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1809347/is-an-iphone-call-recorder-theoretically-possible)

I am an iPhone devleoper.
  I want to record the conversation during phone call.
  I don't know apple is allowing to do this or not.
  If yes, than can anybody guide me how can i do this?

- Basically In my app ,I am recording 1 audio .
  Now when i call someone from my contact ,I want to play that audio as well as record the conversation.
  Both play and record thing I want.
  I am confused whether it is possible or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no public API for recording the calls made (or received) by the built-in Phone app.

You will have to implement your own phone calling mechanism.  You'll probably want to use VoIP.  (That is what [Google Voice](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/google-voice/id318698524?mt=8) uses, for example.)  You'll need to run your own server on the Internet, or contract with an existing VoIP service.  You'll want to use in-app purchase to let the user buy minutes, because it costs money to run your own server or use a third-party service.

Comment: Can i use VoIP in my app? I mean can i implement it in my application?

Comment: You are allowed to implement it in your app.  Many apps in the app store already do.  You might even find some free code on the net you can use to help.

Answer (score 0):

There is no public API for this. No app headed for the App Store can record phone calls made with the standard Phone app.

Comment: I heard that on apple store there are some apps which can record the conversation.so how come they do that? i need to do this please help me out..