# Phone Call Recording in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, ios10, audio-recording, callkit

In phone.app (iOS Native calling app), Is there any mean by which I can perform task like

1.Identify the caller (Incoming and Outgoing), so that on the behalf of caller I can perform some task.
2.Recording of call.
3.If some audio recording already in running state then how a call record can be handled.?

In my finding a reached at below outcome
1. CTCallCenter class have the information about call but i don't get phone number.
2. Call recording is not possible as there is no Apple API to do so.
There are some apps on app store but they are not capable to record the call from phone.app.
 I think they are recording the call by their server (3 Way call.)
3. I think it will lead towards a crash as phone call is a high priority task so that the control of mic and speaker is given to phone call.

Is there any way to get expected result ? 
Is it possible with call kit.?

Thanks.

Comment: Check these: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1809347/how-can-i-record-a-conversation-phone-call-on-ios and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13656753/record-the-conversation-of-phone-ios

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, what you're asking for is not possible as far as I know. Your app can be aware of incoming calls and their states, but not access the phone number. Using the CallKit APIs introduced in iOS 10, you can provide a label for an incoming phone number, but even then you have to set up a predefined list of numbers and labels. Your app won't know which number called. See "Identifying Incoming Callers" in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/callkit) and [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38098036/how-to-get-the-incoming-call-number-by-using-callkit).

As for recording calls, there are no ways to do this without introducing a third party to the call, or routing the call to a service you control.

Regards,
Martin