# Is is possible to develop an app to record phone conversations for iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, core-telephony

Is it possible to develop an app to handle an incoming phone call for iPhone? I mean, I'm thinking to develop an app to record phone conversation for both outgoing and incoming calls.

If it is an outgoing call, can user make a standard phone call and the voice conversation be recorded?

If it is an incoming call, can app be opened/activated when there is an incoming call and the user talk while the conversation is recorded?

(There is a [Core Telephone Framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CoreTelephonyFrameworkReference/_index.html): 
 but I don't know if it would help.)

Can anyone advise?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1809347/is-an-iphone-call-recorder-theoretically-possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ignoring legal implications, it is not possible over their provider's network.

```
(ex: Verizon)
```

[This](http://www.macworld.com/article/2010545/recording-your-iphone-calls.html) article goes into a little more detail.

Comment: This is won't be for US market. So, any help?

Comment: If you want to do something where the call is actually routed through your own servers, then it's possible, but if I understand what you're trying to do, it's not going to work.