# How to record a Phone Call in iphone in locally?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

Hi i am new to iOS development, i want to develop a one app for recording call conversations,for that i searched it. The result is "This is not accepted by the apple store." But my app for enterprises app. So please tell me,if there is any other alternative way for this.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is an iPhone call recorder app theoretically possible?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1809347/is-an-iphone-call-recorder-app-theoretically-possible)

Answer (score 1):

You will not be able to access the audio nor the microphone from the calls. The reason is because of the architecture of iOS. The microphone and speaker is owned by the app which is using it at that time, so no apps made by developers can accomplish what you are suggesting.  (certainly Apple can override this sandbox feature).
Try Android.