# iOS - call recorder tweak

Tags: ios, jailbreak, tweak

I'm trying to create a tweak to record iOS phone calls. I've copied the code from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1809347/how-can-i-record-conversation-phone-call-on-ios) to create a tweak that can record calls and built the tweak with iOSOpenDev. There are few problems. When i disconnect the call, the phone resprings and there is a file with no sound in it (the file is created, but the size of it is only 28kb).

P.S. 1:In that post they said the tweak should be loaded in the `mediaserverd` daemon. How can i do that?

P.S. 2: I just installed the .plist and .dylib file in `/Library/MobileSubstrate/Dynamic Libraries/` .

P.S. 3: I'm using XCode 4.5 and iOSOpenDev to build it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've figured it out.
The tweak should be loaded in mediaserverd daemon. This can be done by editing the .plist of the tweak. There should be an `Executable` filter in the plist:

```
Filter = {
  Executables = ("mediaserverd");
};
```

For more information about CydiaSubstrate (MobileSubstrate) check:

[iPhoneDevWiki - MobileSubstrate](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/MobileSubstrate)

[CydiaSubstrate Documentation](http://www.cydiasubstrate.com/inject/darwin/)

And I think this tweak is only for iPhone 4S and above.

Comment: I have the Question that you had. Could you please share sample code with me. I m confuse in creating tweak with this sample [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1809347/how-can-i-record-conversation-phone-call-on-ios). It would be nice if you could help me creating tweak with sample. I m also using iOSOpenDev.