# How can I change the voice data iPhone sends to cellular network

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, audio, audio-recording

I have this code that records a voice call in iPhone. What I'm trying to is change the data that goes to the cellular network. Specifically I think I need access to the voice data after they are modulated in dsp and are ready to send to the cellular network.

I want to apply some stream cipher to the data that already are modulated.

Is this the right class to look for? Any suggestions are welcome.

original code from [How can I record a conversation / phone call on iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1809347/how-can-i-record-conversation-phone-call-on-ios)

```
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>
#import <libkern/OSAtomic.h>

//CoreTelephony.framework
extern "C" CFStringRef const kCTCallStatusChangeNotification;
extern "C" CFStringRef const kCTCallStatus;
extern "C" id CTTelephonyCenterGetDefault();
extern "C" void CTTelephonyCenterAddObserver(id ct, void* observer, CFNotificationCallback callBack, CFStringRef name, void *object, CFNotificationSuspensionBehavior sb);
extern "C" int CTGetCurrentCallCount();
enum
{
    kCTCallStatusActive = 1,
    kCTCallStatusHeld = 2,
    kCTCallStatusOutgoing = 3,
    kCTCallStatusIncoming = 4,
    kCTCallStatusHanged = 5
};

NSString* kMicFilePath = @"/var/mobile/Media/DCIM/mic.caf";
NSString* kSpeakerFilePath = @"/var/mobile/Media/DCIM/speaker.caf";
NSString* kResultFilePath = @"/var/mobile/Media/DCIM/result.m4a";

OSSpinLock phoneCallIsActiveLock = 0;
OSSpinLock speakerLock = 0;
OSSpinLock micLock = 0;

ExtAudioFileRef micFile = NULL;
ExtAudioFileRef speakerFile = NULL;

BOOL phoneCallIsActive = NO;

void Convert()
{
    //File URLs
    CFURLRef micUrl = CFURLCreateWithFileSystemPath(NULL, (CFStringRef)kMicFilePath, kCFURLPOSIXPathStyle, false);
    CFURLRef speakerUrl = CFURLCreateWithFileSystemPath(NULL, (CFStringRef)kSpeakerFilePath, kCFURLPOSIXPathStyle, false);
    CFURLRef mixUrl = CFURLCreateWithFileSystemPath(NULL, (CFStringRef)kResultFilePath, kCFURLPOSIXPathStyle, false);

    ExtAudioFileRef micFile = NULL;
    ExtAudioFileRef speakerFile = NULL;
    ExtAudioFileRef mixFile = NULL;

    //Opening input files (speaker and mic)
    ExtAudioFileOpenURL(micUrl, &micFile);
    ExtAudioFileOpenURL(speakerUrl, &speakerFile);

    //Reading input file audio format (mono LPCM)
    AudioStreamBasicDescription inputFormat, outputFormat;
    UInt32 descSize = sizeof(inputFormat);
    ExtAudioFileGetProperty(micFile, kExtAudioFileProperty_FileDataFormat, &descSize, &inputFormat);
    int sampleSize = inputFormat.mBytesPerFrame;

    //Filling input stream format for output file (stereo LPCM)
    FillOutASBDForLPCM(inputFormat, inputFormat.mSampleRate, 2, inputFormat.mBitsPerChannel, inputFormat.mBitsPerChannel, true, false, false);

    //Filling output file audio format (AAC)
    memset(&outputFormat, 0, sizeof(outputFormat));
    outputFormat.mFormatID = kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC;
    outputFormat.mSampleRate = 8000;
    outputFormat.mFormatFlags = kMPEG4Object_AAC_Main;
    outputFormat.mChannelsPerFrame = 2;

    //Opening output file
    ExtAudioFileCreateWithURL(mixUrl, kAudioFileM4AType, &outputFormat, NULL, kAudioFileFlags_EraseFile, &mixFile);
    ExtAudioFileSetProperty(mixFile, kExtAudioFileProperty_ClientDataFormat, sizeof(inputFormat), &inputFormat);

    //Freeing URLs
    CFRelease(micUrl);
    CFRelease(speakerUrl);
    CFRelease(mixUrl);

    //Setting up audio buffers
    int bufferSizeInSamples = 64 * 1024;

    AudioBufferList micBuffer;
    micBuffer.mNumberBuffers = 1;
    micBuffer.mBuffers[0].mNumberChannels = 1;
    micBuffer.mBuffers[0].mDataByteSize = sampleSize * bufferSizeInSamples;
    micBuffer.mBuffers[0].mData = malloc(micBuffer.mBuffers[0].mDataByteSize);

    AudioBufferList speakerBuffer;
    speakerBuffer.mNumberBuffers = 1;
    speakerBuffer.mBuffers[0].mNumberChannels = 1;
    speakerBuffer.mBuffers[0].mDataByteSize = sampleSize * bufferSizeInSamples;
    speakerBuffer.mBuffers[0].mData = malloc(speakerBuffer.mBuffers[0].mDataByteSize);

    AudioBufferList mixBuffer;
    mixBuffer.mNumberBuffers = 1;
    mixBuffer.mBuffers[0].mNumberChannels = 2;
    mixBuffer.mBuffers[0].mDataByteSize = sampleSize * bufferSizeInSamples * 2;
    mixBuffer.mBuffers[0].mData = malloc(mixBuffer.mBuffers[0].mDataByteSize);

    //Converting
    while (true)
    {
        //Reading data from input files
        UInt32 framesToRead = bufferSizeInSamples;
        ExtAudioFileRead(micFile, &framesToRead, &micBuffer);
        ExtAudioFileRead(speakerFile, &framesToRead, &speakerBuffer);
        if (framesToRead == 0)
        {
            break;
        }

        //Building interleaved stereo buffer - left channel is mic, right - speaker
        for (int i = 0; i < framesToRead; i++)
        {
            memcpy((char*)mixBuffer.mBuffers[0].mData + i * sampleSize * 2, (char*)micBuffer.mBuffers[0].mData + i * sampleSize, sampleSize);
            memcpy((char*)mixBuffer.mBuffers[0].mData + i * sampleSize * 2 + sampleSize, (char*)speakerBuffer.mBuffers[0].mData + i * sampleSize, sampleSize);
        }

        //Writing to output file - LPCM will be converted to AAC
        ExtAudioFileWrite(mixFile, framesToRead, &mixBuffer);
    }

    //Closing files
    ExtAudioFileDispose(micFile);
    ExtAudioFileDispose(speakerFile);
    ExtAudioFileDispose(mixFile);

    //Freeing audio buffers
    free(micBuffer.mBuffers[0].mData);
    free(speakerBuffer.mBuffers[0].mData);
    free(mixBuffer.mBuffers[0].mData);
}

void Cleanup()
{
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:kMicFilePath error:NULL];
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:kSpeakerFilePath error:NULL];
}

void CoreTelephonyNotificationCallback(CFNotificationCenterRef center, void *observer, CFStringRef name, const void *object, CFDictionaryRef userInfo)
{
    NSDictionary* data = (NSDictionary*)userInfo;

    if ([(NSString*)name isEqualToString:(NSString*)kCTCallStatusChangeNotification])
    {
        int currentCallStatus = [data[(NSString*)kCTCallStatus] integerValue];

        if (currentCallStatus == kCTCallStatusOutgoing || currentCallStatus == kCTCallStatusActive)
        {
            OSSpinLockLock(&phoneCallIsActiveLock);
            phoneCallIsActive = YES;
            OSSpinLockUnlock(&phoneCallIsActiveLock);
        }
        else if (currentCallStatus == kCTCallStatusHanged)
        {
            if (CTGetCurrentCallCount() > 0)
            {
                return;
            }

            OSSpinLockLock(&phoneCallIsActiveLock);
            phoneCallIsActive = NO;
            OSSpinLockUnlock(&phoneCallIsActiveLock);

            //Closing mic file
            OSSpinLockLock(&micLock);
            if (micFile != NULL)
            {
                ExtAudioFileDispose(micFile);
            }
            micFile = NULL;
            OSSpinLockUnlock(&micLock);

            //Closing speaker file
            OSSpinLockLock(&speakerLock);
            if (speakerFile != NULL)
            {
                ExtAudioFileDispose(speakerFile);
            }
            speakerFile = NULL;
            OSSpinLockUnlock(&speakerLock);

            Convert();
            Cleanup();
        }
    }
}

OSStatus(*AudioUnitProcess_orig)(AudioUnit unit, AudioUnitRenderActionFlags *ioActionFlags, const AudioTimeStamp *inTimeStamp, UInt32 inNumberFrames, AudioBufferList *ioData);
OSStatus AudioUnitProcess_hook(AudioUnit unit, AudioUnitRenderActionFlags *ioActionFlags, const AudioTimeStamp *inTimeStamp, UInt32 inNumberFrames, AudioBufferList *ioData)
{
    OSSpinLockLock(&phoneCallIsActiveLock);
    if (phoneCallIsActive == NO)
    {
        OSSpinLockUnlock(&phoneCallIsActiveLock);
        return AudioUnitProcess_orig(unit, ioActionFlags, inTimeStamp, inNumberFrames, ioData);
    }
    OSSpinLockUnlock(&phoneCallIsActiveLock);

    ExtAudioFileRef* currentFile = NULL;
    OSSpinLock* currentLock = NULL;

    AudioComponentDescription unitDescription = {0};
    AudioComponentGetDescription(AudioComponentInstanceGetComponent(unit), &unitDescription);
    //'agcc', 'mbdp' - iPhone 4S, iPhone 5
    //'agc2', 'vrq2' - iPhone 5C, iPhone 5S
    if (unitDescription.componentSubType == 'agcc' || unitDescription.componentSubType == 'agc2')
    {
        currentFile = &micFile;
        currentLock = &micLock;
    }
    else if (unitDescription.componentSubType == 'mbdp' || unitDescription.componentSubType == 'vrq2')
    {
        currentFile = &speakerFile;
        currentLock = &speakerLock;
    }

    if (currentFile != NULL)
    {
        OSSpinLockLock(currentLock);

        //Opening file
        if (*currentFile == NULL)
        {
            //Obtaining input audio format
            AudioStreamBasicDescription desc;
            UInt32 descSize = sizeof(desc);
            AudioUnitGetProperty(unit, kAudioUnitProperty_StreamFormat, kAudioUnitScope_Input, 0, &desc, &descSize);

            //Opening audio file
            CFURLRef url = CFURLCreateWithFileSystemPath(NULL, (CFStringRef)((currentFile == &micFile) ? kMicFilePath : kSpeakerFilePath), kCFURLPOSIXPathStyle, false);
            ExtAudioFileRef audioFile = NULL;
            OSStatus result = ExtAudioFileCreateWithURL(url, kAudioFileCAFType, &desc, NULL, kAudioFileFlags_EraseFile, &audioFile);
            if (result != 0)
            {
                *currentFile = NULL;
            }
            else
            {
                *currentFile = audioFile;

                //Writing audio format
                ExtAudioFileSetProperty(*currentFile, kExtAudioFileProperty_ClientDataFormat, sizeof(desc), &desc);
            }
            CFRelease(url);
        }
        else
        {
            //Writing audio buffer
            ExtAudioFileWrite(*currentFile, inNumberFrames, ioData);
        }

        OSSpinLockUnlock(currentLock);
    }

    return AudioUnitProcess_orig(unit, ioActionFlags, inTimeStamp, inNumberFrames, ioData);
}

__attribute__((constructor))
static void initialize()
{
    CTTelephonyCenterAddObserver(CTTelephonyCenterGetDefault(), NULL, CoreTelephonyNotificationCallback, NULL, NULL, CFNotificationSuspensionBehaviorHold);

    MSHookFunction(AudioUnitProcess, AudioUnitProcess_hook, &AudioUnitProcess_orig);
}
```

Comment: I don't think you can access that data. What my code does is hooks resampling process. Audio streams being resampled before they go into the baseband. After that they're going straight into the baseband where modulation should be done I think. iOS doen't have access to the cellular network, quallcomm baseband does which has it's own CPU, OS, memory space, DSPs, antennas etc. iOS and baseband communicate through special interface and protocol, they're two completely separate things.

Comment: @creker If you hear the sound of the *mic* that is recorded by your code, is modulated and sounds pretty much like the phone call does. So I suspect that the compression is already done?

Comment: @john_bassos resampling already done but then it needs to be compressed (probably AMR) and modulated (GMSK or something) to be actually transferred over the air. I don't remember AMR compression  going on where my hooks are, I don't even think it's done in software but rather it's hardware accelerated.

Comment: I do a simple xor in the microphone data of the sender's side. On the the other side of the call the receiver (speaker) i get distorted audio but I can understand what the other says. The problem is if I do the reverse procedure on the receiver ( xor with the same number again ) I get an even more distorted result! Do you know why this happens or if I should hook in a function before audiounitprocess?

Comment: Right after "//Writing audio buffer" , add: if (currentFile==&micFile){ } and apply transformation to the ioData inside that scope

Comment: OSSpinLock is unsafe on iOS: http://openradar.appspot.com/23896366