# Access iPhone voice call data

Tags: ios, call, record, jailbreak, voice

I am trying to figure out which framework should I try to hook to, so I can have access to the voice call modulated data.

I have access to the data after the AudioUnit has processed them from the code by this post: [How can I record a conversation / phone call on iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1809347/how-can-i-record-conversation-phone-call-on-ios/21571219#21571219)

Any help is apreciated