# Record telephone calls placed from iOS enterprise apps

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, audio-recording, privacy

I'm writing an app that would record calls placed by sales representative and send it to managers, so that the managers can monitor his sales closely and efficiently.

So - I want to be able to record just the telephone calls placed from my app (that too with a disclaimer) because it's not right to invade their privacy. At the same time, I need to know how well my employee is performing. Any ideas on how to achieve this?

I think Apple wouldn't check my app because it will be an Enterprise App (I've read that there is no App Store review for enterprise apps). Though I wouldn't like 3rd party VoIP get involved, I'm interested to know how to proceed in that direction as an option. Jailbreaking is definitely not an option given the situation.

Answer (score 5):

There is no public API to do this.

Since you are not going to release it in the appstore you have the advantage of using private APIs.

The iPhone call history is stored in “call_history.db” which is located at the following path:

> /private/var/root/Library/CallHistory/call_history.db

Now we can make use of sqlite C APIs to extract it.

Now that we know the call history db path and schema, we can see that we are interested in the “call” table. Thanks to the above link, we know what exactly is stored in this table:

Now we should write some code to access that. The following code accesses the “call” table and stores the retrieved values in an array of dictionaries. You could write your own class and use an array of objects of that class:

```
NSString *callHisoryDatabasePath = @"/private/var/wireless/Library/CallHistory/call_history.db";
BOOL callHistoryFileExist = FALSE;
callHistoryFileExist = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:callHisoryDatabasePath];
[fileManager release];
NSMutableArray *callHistory = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

if(callHistoryFileExist) {
    if ([fileManager isReadableFileAtPath:callHisoryDatabasePath]) {
        sqlite3 *database;
        if(sqlite3_open([callHisoryDatabasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {
            sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;
            NSString *sqlStatement = [NSString stringWithString:@"SELECT * FROM call;"];

            int errorCode = sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [sqlStatement UTF8String], -1, 
                                                &compiledStatement, NULL);
            if( errorCode == SQLITE_OK) {
                int count = 1;

                while(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
                    // Read the data from the result row
                    NSMutableDictionary *callHistoryItem = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
                    int numberOfColumns = sqlite3_column_count(compiledStatement);
                    NSString *data;
                    NSString *columnName;

                    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfColumns; i++) {
                        columnName = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:
                                    (char *)sqlite3_column_name(compiledStatement, i)];
                        data = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:
                                (char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, i)];

                        [callHistoryItem setObject:data forKey:columnName];

                        [columnName release];
                        [data release];
                    }
                    [callHistory addObject:callHistoryItem];
                    [callHistoryItem release];
                    count++;
                }
            }
            else {
                NSLog(@"Failed to retrieve table");
                NSLog(@"Error Code: %d", errorCode);
            }
            sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);
        }
    }
}
```

[Reference](https://iosstuff.wordpress.com/2011/08/19/accessing-iphone-call-history/)

Answer (score 0):

You are true, that neither it is mandatory nor you don't need an approval.
You have to distribute an app by yourself and as you are deploying an enterprise app, you should not distribute the app outside your organisation. Your customers also will have to sign your app with their own enterprise certificate.

But - let's back your question: **It is not possible to access iOS calling API** in any ways.
I haven't tested Durai's solution, who suggest to use SQLite store.

Comment: The SQLite Store is created by iOS Call app and we've to read it

Comment: It is only possible in older iOS versions by using call_history.db file which contains the history.

Comment: If I could really get the call history, that;s a start. How about audio recordings? No way possible?

Comment: Have you meant data from Voice Memos app?

Comment: @pedrouan - in newer versions check the path using the following code `NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager]; 
NSDirectoryEnumerator *dirnum = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] enumeratorAtPath: @"/private/"]; 
NSString *nextItem = [NSString string]; 
while( (nextItem = [dirnum nextObject])) {
    if ([[nextItem pathExtension] isEqualToString: @"db"] || 
        [[nextItem pathExtension] isEqualToString: @"sqlitedb"]) { 
        if ([fileManager isReadableFileAtPath:nextItem]) { 
            NSLog(@"%@", nextItem); 
        } 
    } 
}`

Comment: @Manjuhere If you meant call recording, simply you can't. Apple, as the company with the biggest efforts in maintaining of privacy, won't allow such a possiblity. You may try with jailbroken devices, but not with ones app users will have. At least I don't think so. Call recording won't be possible to access as it is illegal in many countries, that Apple distributes its products to.

Comment: @Manjuhere - Voice recording is easy stuff.You mean call recording ..if that's the case ...here is a good link to [start](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21571219/730807).

Comment: This link you provided could work on JAILBROKEN devices only. Manjuhere may need to distribute the apps to wider enterprise audience.