# is Call recording available in ios

Tags: ios, phone-call

I am confused with call recording. Is Call recording available or not??. Some are saying [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1809347/how-can-i-record-a-conversation-phone-call-on-ios) that not available. How the these apps approved by apple [link1](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/call-recorder-free-record/id637819447?mt=8) [link2](https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/call-recorder-intcall/id521680097?mt=8).

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible. Based on the descriptions of those apps, they use third party services, not iOS SDK APIs.

> Steps for recording an incoming (existing) call:
>
> 1) Open Call Recorder
>
> 2) Go to the Record screen and tap the Record button
>
> 3) Your existing call is put on hold and **your phone will dial our recording number**
>
> 4) Once connected to our recording number, tap the Merge button on your screen to create a 3-way call between your existing call and our recording line

Comment: So can i develop using third parties and submit to appstore??

Comment: @Sekhar22 If you're looking to build an app you should familiarise yourself with with the review guidelines. https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/