# iOS - Record the Voice while phone call in Objective c

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode, avfoundation, record

Is it possible for an app which records the voice of the user while a phone call?

I searched for it and the AVFoundation Framework seems to stop recording when a phone call is incoming. I don't want to record the whole call, I am just interested in record what the user of the iPhone is saying.

I know that this possibility might be a safety risk, but it would be nice for e.g an interview.

In case of no possibility to do it like i want, i have to create my own VoIP connection and then i can record it, am i right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no direct way or API from Apple to achieve your need of recording voice  while phone call. `AVAudioRecorder` wont support it as well. Because it will be stopped once the call begin. 
But there are work around like hook `AudioUnitProcess` in order to access phone call's audio streams and save it as m4a. This will work without jailbreak but not sure this will be accepted by Apple app store review team.

For more info on the work around check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1809347/how-can-i-record-a-conversation-phone-call-on-ios) SO accepted answer.

Also creating your own VoIP connection method work for recording during phone call.

Comment: Thank you for the information, i think i will try to do my own VoIP connection to exclude review problems.

Answer (score 0):

There are Cydia tweaks which are able to do that. For example CallRecorder.

Comment: Thank you, but i was looking for a solution which is working without a jailbreak.