# How can I access phone call audio stream while calling on iOS 11?

Tags: ios, phone-call, recording

I am in need of building call recording application.
I can handle incoming/outgoing phone call event now.
But there is no solution found to access to phone call audio stream.

Referenced [How can I record a conversation / phone call on iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1809347/how-can-i-record-a-conversation-phone-call-on-ios), but working on only jailbreaken.

How to access phone call audio stream and record it?

Comment: Are you looking for a solution for non-jail broken phones?  If so, there isn't one unless you are talking about a voip call made by your app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple does not currently allow it: it is not possible to spy on conversations on a non-jailbroken iPhone, even with potential user consent.